# Algorithm to generate random 2D polygon

Tags: algorithm, matlab, random, polygon, computational-geometry

I'm not sure how to approach this problem. I'm not sure how complex a task it is. My aim is to have an algorithm that generates any polygon. My only requirement is that the polygon is not complex (i.e. sides do not intersect). I'm using Matlab for doing the maths but anything abstract is welcome.

Any aid/direction?

EDIT:

I was thinking more of code that could generate any polygon even things like this:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "random?"  Do you know anything about the distribution you're trying to generate?

Comment: @templatetypedef Apparently he wants an algorithm that produces random **simple** polygons, since in general taking an arbitrary order of n points will also produce self-intersecting polygons.

Comment: put random number of points in random positions on circle with random radius and connect them consecutive?

Comment: Such a polygon has a name - simple polygon, actually.

Comment: `...anything abstract is welcome`. Here is related paper: Hada, Pratik Shankar, [**"Approaches for Generating 2D Shapes"**](http://digitalscholarship.unlv.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=3183&context=thesesdissertations) (2014). UNLV Theses, Dissertations, Professional Papers, and Capstones. 2182.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There's a neat way to do what you want by taking advantage of the MATLAB classes [`DelaunayTri`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/delaunaytri-class.html) and [`TriRep`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/trirep-class.html) and the various methods they employ for handling triangular meshes. The code below follows these steps to create an arbitrary [simple polygon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_polygon):

- Generate a number of random points equal to the desired number of sides plus a fudge factor. The fudge factor ensures that, regardless of the result of the triangulation, we should have enough facets to be able to trim the triangular mesh down to a polygon with the desired number of sides.
- Create a Delaunay triangulation of the points, resulting in a [convex polygon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_polygon) that is constructed from a series of triangular facets.
- If the boundary of the triangulation has more edges than desired, pick a random triangular facet on the edge that has a unique vertex (i.e. the triangle only shares one edge with the rest of the triangulation). Removing this triangular facet will reduce the number of boundary edges.
- If the boundary of the triangulation has fewer edges than desired, or the previous step was unable to find a triangle to remove, pick a random triangular facet on the edge that has only one of its edges on the triangulation boundary. Removing this triangular facet will increase the number of boundary edges.
- If no triangular facets can be found matching the above criteria, post a warning that a polygon with the desired number of sides couldn't be found and return the x and y coordinates of the current triangulation boundary. Otherwise, keep removing triangular facets until the desired number of edges is met, then return the x and y coordinates of triangulation boundary.

Here's the resulting function:

```
function [x, y, dt] = simple_polygon(numSides)

    if numSides < 3
        x = [];
        y = [];
        dt = DelaunayTri();
        return
    end

    oldState = warning('off', 'MATLAB:TriRep:PtsNotInTriWarnId');

    fudge = ceil(numSides/10);
    x = rand(numSides+fudge, 1);
    y = rand(numSides+fudge, 1);
    dt = DelaunayTri(x, y);
    boundaryEdges = freeBoundary(dt);
    numEdges = size(boundaryEdges, 1);

    while numEdges ~= numSides
        if numEdges > numSides
            triIndex = vertexAttachments(dt, boundaryEdges(:,1));
            triIndex = triIndex(randperm(numel(triIndex)));
            keep = (cellfun('size', triIndex, 2) ~= 1);
        end
        if (numEdges < numSides) || all(keep)
            triIndex = edgeAttachments(dt, boundaryEdges);
            triIndex = triIndex(randperm(numel(triIndex)));
            triPoints = dt([triIndex{:}], :);
            keep = all(ismember(triPoints, boundaryEdges(:,1)), 2);
        end
        if all(keep)
            warning('Couldn''t achieve desired number of sides!');
            break
        end
        triPoints = dt.Triangulation;
        triPoints(triIndex{find(~keep, 1)}, :) = [];
        dt = TriRep(triPoints, x, y);
        boundaryEdges = freeBoundary(dt);
        numEdges = size(boundaryEdges, 1);
    end

    boundaryEdges = [boundaryEdges(:,1); boundaryEdges(1,1)];
    x = dt.X(boundaryEdges, 1);
    y = dt.X(boundaryEdges, 2);

    warning(oldState);

end
```

And here are some sample results:

[image]

The generated polygons could be either convex or [concave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concave_polygon), but for larger numbers of desired sides they will almost certainly be concave. The polygons are also generated from points randomly generated within a unit square, so polygons with larger numbers of sides will generally look like they have a "squarish" boundary (such as the lower right example above with the 50-sided polygon). To modify this general bounding shape, you can change the way the initial `x` and `y` points are randomly chosen (i.e. from a Gaussian distribution, etc.).

Comment: +1 As it's a good answer though there's another condition you have to check.  If you are removing a triangle with just one edge on the hull, you have to make sure that the opposing vertex is not on the hull, or you'll end up with two polygons with one common point.

Comment: @Shane: That situation is already accounted for in the code above. The line `keep = all(ismember(triPoints, boundaryEdges(:,1)), 2);` marks a triangle to be kept if all of its vertices lie on the free boundary, which is the case if a triangle has both one edge and the opposing vertex on the free boundary. This kind of triangle will never be removed from the triangulation, avoiding splitting of the polygon in two.

Answer (score 48):

I took @MitchWheat and @templatetypedef's idea of sampling points on a circle and took it a bit farther.

In my application I need to be able to control how weird the polygons are, ie start with regular polygons and as I crank up the parameters they get increasingly chaotic. The basic idea is as stated by @templatetypedef; walk around the circle taking a random angular step each time, and at each step put a point at a random radius. In equations I'm generating the angular steps as
[image: equations for the angles and radii of the vertices]

where theta_i and r_i give the angle and radius of each point relative to the centre, U(min, max) pulls a random number from a uniform distribution, and N(mu, sigma) pulls a random number from a Gaussian distribution, and clip(x, min, max) thresholds a value into a range. This gives us two really nice parameters to control how wild the polygons are - epsilon which I'll call **irregularity** controls whether or not the points are uniformly space angularly around the circle, and sigma which I'll call **spikeyness** which controls how much the points can vary from the circle of radius r_ave. If you set both of these to 0 then you get perfectly regular polygons, if you crank them up then the polygons get crazier.

I whipped this up quickly in python and got stuff like this:
[image: some polygons I generated]

Here's the full python code:

```py
import math, random
from typing import List, Tuple


def generate_polygon(center: Tuple[float, float], avg_radius: float,
                     irregularity: float, spikiness: float,
                     num_vertices: int) -> List[Tuple[float, float]]:
    """
    Start with the center of the polygon at center, then creates the
    polygon by sampling points on a circle around the center.
    Random noise is added by varying the angular spacing between
    sequential points, and by varying the radial distance of each
    point from the centre.

    Args:
        center (Tuple[float, float]):
            a pair representing the center of the circumference used
            to generate the polygon.
        avg_radius (float):
            the average radius (distance of each generated vertex to
            the center of the circumference) used to generate points
            with a normal distribution.
        irregularity (float):
            variance of the spacing of the angles between consecutive
            vertices.
        spikiness (float):
            variance of the distance of each vertex to the center of
            the circumference.
        num_vertices (int):
            the number of vertices of the polygon.
    Returns:
        List[Tuple[float, float]]: list of vertices, in CCW order.
    """
    # Parameter check
    if irregularity < 0 or irregularity > 1:
        raise ValueError("Irregularity must be between 0 and 1.")
    if spikiness < 0 or spikiness > 1:
        raise ValueError("Spikiness must be between 0 and 1.")

    irregularity *= 2 * math.pi / num_vertices
    spikiness *= avg_radius
    angle_steps = random_angle_steps(num_vertices, irregularity)

    # now generate the points
    points = []
    angle = random.uniform(0, 2 * math.pi)
    for i in range(num_vertices):
        radius = clip(random.gauss(avg_radius, spikiness), 0, 2 * avg_radius)
        point = (center[0] + radius * math.cos(angle),
                 center[1] + radius * math.sin(angle))
        points.append(point)
        angle += angle_steps[i]

    return points
```

```py
def random_angle_steps(steps: int, irregularity: float) -> List[float]:
    """Generates the division of a circumference in random angles.

    Args:
        steps (int):
            the number of angles to generate.
        irregularity (float):
            variance of the spacing of the angles between consecutive vertices.
    Returns:
        List[float]: the list of the random angles.
    """
    # generate n angle steps
    angles = []
    lower = (2 * math.pi / steps) - irregularity
    upper = (2 * math.pi / steps) + irregularity
    cumsum = 0
    for i in range(steps):
        angle = random.uniform(lower, upper)
        angles.append(angle)
        cumsum += angle

    # normalize the steps so that point 0 and point n+1 are the same
    cumsum /= (2 * math.pi)
    for i in range(steps):
        angles[i] /= cumsum
    return angles
```

```py
def clip(value, lower, upper):
    """
    Given an interval, values outside the interval are clipped to the interval
    edges.
    """
    return min(upper, max(value, lower))
```

---

@MateuszKonieczny here is code to create an image of a polygon from a list of vertices.

```py
vertices = generate_polygon(center=(250, 250),
                            avg_radius=100,
                            irregularity=0.35,
                            spikiness=0.2,
                            num_vertices=16)

black = (0, 0, 0)
white = (255, 255, 255)
img = Image.new('RGB', (500, 500), white)
im_px_access = img.load()
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)

# either use .polygon(), if you want to fill the area with a solid colour
draw.polygon(vertices, outline=black, fill=white)

# or .line() if you want to control the line thickness, or use both methods together!
draw.line(vertices + [vertices[0]], width=2, fill=black)

img.show()

# now you can save the image (img), or do whatever else you want with it.
```

Comment: Unfortunately due to nature of this algorithm (it uses polar coordinates) some types of polygons cannot be created. Like this one: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bxa3b.png

Comment: This type of polygon is called [star convex](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/StarConvex.html).

Answer (score 17):

For a convex 2D polygon (totally off the top of my head):

1. Generate a random radius, R
2. Generate N random points on the circumference of a circle of Radius R
3. Move around the circle and draw straight lines between adjacent points on the circle.

Comment: I might also add that in general, the problem is finding a non intersecting hamiltonian cycle on a graph. Apparently there are (n-1)!/2 such cycles for a n-vertex graph, meaning that n random points define (n-1)!/2 different polygons. If you have a function that detects whether two edges intersect (which is very easy), then you can randomly pick up a point, randomly pick another, test whether this edges intersects with existing edges or not and keep/reject the point and so on. This way you can create general random polygons on the plane.

Comment: This approach with the improvement suggested by @templatetypedef sometimes can produce invalid polygons, unfortunately. For example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNGd5.png

Answer (score 6):

As @templatetypedef and @MitchWheat said, it is easy to do so by generating `N` random angles and radii.  It is important to sort the angles, otherwise it will not be a simple polygon. Note that I am using a neat trick to draw closed curves - I described it in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8545077/connecting-final-and-initial-point-in-simple-x-y-plot/8545625#8545625).  By the way, the polygons might be **concave**.

Note that all of these polygons will be star shaped. Generating a more general polygon is not a simple problem at all.
Just to give you a taste of the problem - check out 
 http://www.cosy.sbg.ac.at/~held/projects/rpg/rpg.html
and http://compgeom.cs.uiuc.edu/~jeffe/open/randompoly.html.

[image]

```
function CreateRandomPoly()
    figure();
    colors = {'r','g','b','k'};
    for i=1:5
        [x,y]=CreatePoly();
        c = colors{ mod(i-1,numel(colors))+1};
        plotc(x,y,c);
        hold on;
    end        
end

function [x,y]=CreatePoly()
    numOfPoints = randi(30);
    theta = randi(360,[1 numOfPoints]);
    theta = theta * pi / 180;
    theta = sort(theta);
    rho = randi(200,size(theta));
    [x,y] = pol2cart(theta,rho);    
    xCenter = randi([-1000 1000]);
    yCenter = randi([-1000 1000]);
    x = x + xCenter;
    y = y + yCenter;    
end

function plotc(x,y,varargin)
    x = [x(:) ; x(1)];
    y = [y(:) ; y(1)];
    plot(x,y,varargin{:})
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working port for Matlab of Mike Ounsworth solution. I did not optimized it for matlab. I might update the solution later for that.

```
function [points] = generatePolygon(ctrX, ctrY, aveRadius, irregularity, spikeyness, numVerts)

%{
Start with the centre of the polygon at ctrX, ctrY, 
then creates the polygon by sampling points on a circle around the centre. 
Randon noise is added by varying the angular spacing between sequential points,
and by varying the radial distance of each point from the centre.

Params:
ctrX, ctrY - coordinates of the "centre" of the polygon
aveRadius - in px, the average radius of this polygon, this roughly controls how large the polygon is, really only useful for order of magnitude.
irregularity - [0,1] indicating how much variance there is in the angular spacing of vertices. [0,1] will map to [0, 2pi/numberOfVerts]
spikeyness - [0,1] indicating how much variance there is in each vertex from the circle of radius aveRadius. [0,1] will map to [0, aveRadius]
numVerts - self-explanatory

Returns a list of vertices, in CCW order.

Website: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8997099/algorithm-to-generate-random-2d-polygon
%}


    irregularity = clip( irregularity, 0,1 ) * 2*pi/ numVerts;
    spikeyness = clip( spikeyness, 0,1 ) * aveRadius;

    % generate n angle steps
    angleSteps = [];
    lower = (2*pi / numVerts) - irregularity;
    upper = (2*pi / numVerts) + irregularity;
    sum = 0;
    for i =1:numVerts
        tmp = unifrnd(lower, upper);
        angleSteps(i) = tmp;
        sum = sum + tmp;
    end

    % normalize the steps so that point 0 and point n+1 are the same
    k = sum / (2*pi);
    for i =1:numVerts
        angleSteps(i) = angleSteps(i) / k;
    end

    % now generate the points
    points = [];
    angle = unifrnd(0, 2*pi);
    for i =1:numVerts
        r_i = clip( normrnd(aveRadius, spikeyness), 0, 2*aveRadius);
        x = ctrX + r_i* cos(angle);
        y = ctrY + r_i* sin(angle);
        points(i,:)= [(x),(y)];
        angle = angle + angleSteps(i);
    end

end


function value = clip(x, min, max)
   if( min > max ); value = x; return; end
   if( x  < min ) ; value = min; return; end
   if( x  > max ) ; value = max; return; end
   value = x;
end
```

Answer (score 0):

With a computational geometry library handy, a simple and effective technique is to:

- Generate a random point set
- Compute **concave** hull of the point set
- (Optional) Smooth the hull (to remove narrow slivers, etc)

#### Variable-concavity concave hull

[image]

#### Concave hull with (gaussian) smoothing

[image]

Comment: Show us code mate!

Comment: @zabop See https://github.com/micycle1/PGS