# Connecting random points in MATLAB without intersecting lines

Tags: arrays, matlab, geometry, computational-geometry

I need help with solving this problem. I have randomly generated points (example on **Picture #1**) and I want to connect them with lines (example on **Picture #2**). Lines can't be intersected and after connection, the connected points should look like an irregular area.

```
%Generating random points
xn = randi([3 7],1,10);
yn = randi([3 6],1,10);

%Generated points
xn = [6,3,7,7,6,6,6,4,6,3];
yn = [5,3,4,3,3,6,5,4,6,3];
```

Picture #1:
[image]

Result should be like this:
Picture #2:
[image]

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: With random points, there is no garantee tha a solution exists.

Comment: @AnderBiguri I disagree. even if we cannot solve for the general case, still some practical approaches may be proposed and prove useful.

Comment: @Shai I just made a point so as to get clarification on how to handle the cases where no perfect solution exists.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I suppose for the general case it can be very difficult to come up with a solution. But, assuming your points are scattered "nicely" there is quite a simple solution.

If you sort your points according to the angle above the x axis of the vector connecting the point and the center of the point cloud then:

```
P = [xn;yn]; %// group the points as columns in a matrix
c = mean(P,2); %// center point relative to which you compute the angles
d = bsxfun(@minus, P, c ); %// vectors connecting the central point and the dots
th = atan2(d(2,:),d(1,:)); %// angle above x axis
[st si] = sort(th); 
sP = P(:,si); %// sorting the points
```

And that's about it. To plot the result:

```
sP = [sP sP(:,1)]; %// add the first point again to close the polygon
figure;plot( sP(1,:), sP(2,:), 'x-');axis([0 10 0 10]);
```

This algorithm will fail if several points has the same angle w.r.t the center of the point cloud.

An example with 20 random points:

```
P = rand(2,50);
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You could adapt the code from [another answer I gave](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9008916/52738) for generating random simple polygons of an arbitrary number of sides. The difference here is you already have your set of points chosen and thus implicitly the number of sides you want (i.e. the same as the number of unique points). Here's what the code would look like:

```
xn = [6,3,7,7,6,6,6,4,6,3];  % Sample x points
yn = [5,3,4,3,3,6,5,4,6,3];  % Sample y points
[~, index] = unique([xn.' yn.'], 'rows', 'stable');  % Get the unique pairs of points
x = xn(index).';
y = yn(index).';
numSides = numel(index);
dt = DelaunayTri(x, y);
boundaryEdges = freeBoundary(dt);
numEdges = size(boundaryEdges, 1);

while numEdges ~= numSides
    if numEdges > numSides
        triIndex = vertexAttachments(dt, boundaryEdges(:,1));
        triIndex = triIndex(randperm(numel(triIndex)));
        keep = (cellfun('size', triIndex, 2) ~= 1);
    end
    if (numEdges < numSides) || all(keep)
        triIndex = edgeAttachments(dt, boundaryEdges);
        triIndex = triIndex(randperm(numel(triIndex)));
        triPoints = dt([triIndex{:}], :);
        keep = all(ismember(triPoints, boundaryEdges(:,1)), 2);
    end
    if all(keep)
        warning('Couldn''t achieve desired number of sides!');
        break
    end
    triPoints = dt.Triangulation;
    triPoints(triIndex{find(~keep, 1)}, :) = [];
    dt = TriRep(triPoints, x, y);
    boundaryEdges = freeBoundary(dt);
    numEdges = size(boundaryEdges, 1);
end

boundaryEdges = [boundaryEdges(:,1); boundaryEdges(1,1)];
x = dt.X(boundaryEdges, 1);
y = dt.X(boundaryEdges, 2);
```

And here's the resulting polygon:

```
patch(x,y,'w');
hold on;
plot(x,y,'r*');
axis([0 10 0 10]);
```

[image]

Two things to note:

- Some sets of points (like the ones you chose here) will not have a unique solution. Notice how my code connected the top 4 points in a slightly different way than you did.
- I made use of the [`TriRep`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/trirep-class.html) and [`DelaunayTri`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/delaunaytri-class.html) classes, both of which may be removed in future MATLAB releases in favor of the [`delaunayTriangulation`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/delaunaytriangulation-class.html) class.

Comment: So this basically finds a hamiltonian cycle on the edges of the delaunay triangulation?

Comment: @knedlsepp Yep. It does it by trimming away triangles from the delaunay triangulation (which is a convex hull) until it gets the desired number of sides, which in this case means it ends up connecting all the points.

Comment: Nice. I just tried doing it with [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/19218-matgraph/content/matgraph/samples/html/hamiltonian.html) submission and `d = delaunayTriangulation(P); g = graph(d.edges); C = hamiltonian_cycle(g);`, but the thing is, that for more than 20 nodes it takes considerably longer than your approach. (As in seconds instead of milliseconds.)